# Pods are not deleted after Deployment is deleted in my Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, containerd, calico

After deployment, the pods, replicaset, and deployment are created successfully. However, when I try to delete the Deployment using `kubectl delete deploy nginx-deployment`, the pods and replicaset are not deleted.

My deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2 # 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

I have also tried `kubectl delete deploy nginx-deployment --cascade=background`, but the issue persists. How should I proceed to ensure that the ReplicaSet and Pods are properly deleted when the Deployment is deleted?

Used software:

- Kubernetes 1.27.2
- Installed on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- calico 3.26.0
- containerd 1.6.24

Comment: do you see any issues in the `kube-controller-manager`? is it running fine, check the events and the logs

Comment: What happens when describing the replicasets/pods? Does the status of either of these objects display anything interesting?

Comment: Per your file there is no replica set at all, the kind is Deployment. Maybe you wanted to mean replicaset to the amounts of pods, am i correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by updating the calico version. Seems that there is an incompatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

Im sure you are deleting something that does not exists on the current name space. Do this:

1-get the deployment and its namespace

> kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces

2-pass the namespace to the delete

> kubectl delete -n NAMESPACE deployment nginx-deployment